# What's the best/easiest way to create a usb connection from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, usb, redhat-enterprise-linux, socat, libusb

I'm wondering what's the best way for me to setup a usb connection from Windows to a remote linux servers (Redhat)? I did some Googling and found socat but that was for Linux to Linux, any ideas?

My objective: To ensure my Yubikey is detected on a remote server, to do this I need to ensure I can create the usb connection and send it to the remote server

Thanks! Stduong

Comment: Searching for "usb2ip windows" in Google brings up some suggestions.  I've never tried any of them, though.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win. Check out the "Windows USB/IP client" section. Your linux server runs the `usbipd` daemon and you connect to it from your win client using `usbip.exe`. Setup process requires a few steps though, you need to load a new kernel module on linux and a driver on win machine.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence and Alexm!

Comment: https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win no longer maintained.
for client side use https://github.com/vadimgrn/usbip-win2 instead.